# listen for transitionend event of longer transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to track the longer transition in the code below.

Note that in the given transition :

> transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out, opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;

The top is the shorter and the opacity is the longer transition, and we want to check when opacity transition (as the longer one) has been finished:

```js
function prepareCaptionShow() {
    const prepareCaption = document.querySelector(".prepareCaption");
    prepareCaption.classList.add('prepareCaptionShow');
    prepareCaption.addEventListener('transitionend', prepareCaptionShowEnd);
    function prepareCaptionShowEnd(e) {
        console.log("e.propertyName:", e.propertyName);
        if (e.propertyName === 'opacity') {
            console.log("inside transition"); 
        } 
        prepareCaption.removeEventListener("transitionend", prepareCaptionShowEnd);
    }
} 

setTimeout(() => prepareCaptionShow(), 2500);
```

```css
.prepareCaption {
  position: relative;
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px #100021) drop-shadow(1px .05em 1px #0d021a);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: #f8f7fa;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 0; 
  top: -2.5vh;
  transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out, opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.prepareCaptionShow {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="prepare-container">
     <p class="prepareCaption">text show</p>
</div>
```

As you see the javascript `transitionend` listener only returns the shorter one only(I'm using chrome) is there any solution to track the longer transition (opacity) here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first `transitionend` event you remove the event listener. This will cause the next `transitionend` events not to be captured. If you move the line where you remove the listener inside the `if` statement it will trigger for both events and stops listening at the appropriate moment, after the `opacity` has transitioned.

```js
function prepareCaptionShow() {
    const prepareCaption = document.querySelector(".prepareCaption");
    prepareCaption.classList.add('prepareCaptionShow');
    prepareCaption.addEventListener('transitionend', prepareCaptionShowEnd);
    function prepareCaptionShowEnd(e) {
        if (e.propertyName === 'opacity') {
            console.log(e.propertyName); 
            prepareCaption.removeEventListener("transitionend", prepareCaptionShowEnd);
        }    
    }
} 

setTimeout(() => prepareCaptionShow(), 2500);
```

```css
.prepareCaption {
  position: relative;
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px #100021) drop-shadow(1px .05em 1px #0d021a);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: #f8f7fa;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 0; 
  top: -2.5vh;
  transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out, opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.prepareCaptionShow {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="prepare-container">
     <p class="prepareCaption">text show</p>
</div>
```